# When I update the QPixmap of a QGraphicsPixmapItem, the image disappears from the scene

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have this simple scene showing a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. I update its content periodically from a `QThread`. The first time it is updated, it displays correctly. However the second time around, the image disappears. Any idea why?

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow
import sys

app = QApplication([])
window = QMainWindow()
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
view = QGraphicsView()
scene = QGraphicsScene()
gpix = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
scene.addItem(gpix)
view.setScene(scene)
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()

class Thread(QThread):
  def run(self):
    while True:
      im = np.random.randint(255, size=(256, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
      qim = QImage(im, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
      pix = QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
      gpix.setPixmap(pix)
      self.sleep(1)

thread = Thread()
thread.finished.connect(app.exit)
thread.start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic issues.  Firstly you are potentially accessing the same variable `gpix` simultaneously from multiple threads.  Secondly you are trying to use `QPixmap` from a secondary thread (a thread other than that on which `main` is running).

To fix the first problem you can use a signal/slot to notify the main thread that a new image is available.

For the second problem you can defer the creation of the `QPixmap` from the `QImage` until the point at which the signal is handled.

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow
import sys

app = QApplication([])
window = QMainWindow()
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
view = QGraphicsView()
scene = QGraphicsScene()
gpix = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
scene.addItem(gpix)
view.setScene(scene)
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()

class Thread(QThread):

    # Add a signal that accepts a QImage.
    sig_new_image = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            im = np.random.randint(255, size=(256, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
            qim = QImage(im, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
            pix = QPixmap.fromImage(qim)

            # Emit the signal with the new QImage.
            self.sig_new_image.emit(qim)
            self.sleep(1)

thread = Thread()
thread.finished.connect(app.exit)

# Connect the Thread.sig_new_image signal to a lambda that will update
# the pixmap accordingly.
thread.sig_new_image.connect(lambda i: gpix.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(i)))
thread.start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It works, looks like we can only set pixmap in main thread instead of in other threads